# How can I make language selector work on header instead of footer on Shopify?

Tags: javascript, button, header, shopify, liquid

I've been trying to move the language selector from footer to header. I'm almost there, but it's still not working.

I tried using js snippet on theme.liquid which made the button show up but the function doesn't work. Can anyone help me solve this?
Thanks in advance!

url is https://shtaim.store/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZyAV.png)

I used this code and insert it inside the `<head>` tag.

```html
   <script>
          setTimeout(() => {
              let elementToInsertBefore = document.querySelector(".mobile-icons .header__link.action-area__link")
              let newElement = document.querySelector(".localization.footer-menu__disclosure.is-hidden-medium.is-hidden-mobile-only .selectors-form__item.selectors-form__locale .disclosure.disclosure--i18n.disclosure-text-style-uppercase");
              elementToInsertBefore.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, elementToInsertBefore);
          }, 1000)
    </script>
```

The button is there but doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

just apply this simple css to make the selector into the top left of the page

```css
.disclosure--i18n {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 96px;
    left: 113px;
}
.disclosure__list-wrap {
    transform: translate(18px, 142px);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DeanVanGreunen, I've tried to insert this in different places but unfortunately it doesn't work.